# Outlook is Showing my Name in the body of another persons message when I edit it

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-outlook-2013

So whenever I reply to an email and make an edit in the body of the original email, my name is added to that part of the message and I don't want that. Is there a way to disable this feature for Outlook 2010 and Outlook 2013?

Comment: do you mean as a signature?

Comment: I'm not following.. :)  Your name is added where exactly when you edit?  Can you provide a screenshot of what you are talking about?

Comment: No, not the signature. Basically, when I reply to an email and the user is asking me to answer a question, I type in their part of the message and when i do, my name is automatically typed. This is not in the body of my message but in the body of the original message that I am replying to.

Comment: They already know your name.  I also require a screenshot to understand what your trying to disable.

Comment: "and when i do, my name is automatically typed."  What does this mean exactly?  "Typed" where?  Where you're trying to input your answer?  Please, provide a screenshot example.

Comment: Please don't add the answer to the question; instead, post a self-answer, as you have. Remember to come back to the question in a few days to accept your self-answer (assuming nobody posts a better answer) so the community can tell at a glance that the issue has been resolved.

Comment: I would also encourage you to register an account, so you won't lose the ability to edit, accept etc on your posts if your browser's cookies are cleared for any reason.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Thanks to everyone that helped. This was a really weird problem that I had a tough time to explain but I was able to find the solution to this.

The problem was that Preface comments was checked and that's what caused the issue. This is how you can disable it:

File > Options > Mail > un-check Preface Comments with: